# Scroll/fit image with checkbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, scrollview

I want to show image and add checkbox "Fit to screen" - fit image to visible area.

To fit image to visible area I use the following xaml fragment:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Picture}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

To disable fitting and add scrolling I use the following xaml fragment:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Image Source="{Binding Picture}" Stretch="None"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The question is how to combine fitting and actual size with scroll bars and use checkbox to switch between two states?

**UPDATE:**

The issue is that code `Image/@Stretch=Uniform` behaves in the same way as `Image/@Stretch=None` inside `<ScrollViewer>`. Scrolling is visible in both cases and image is shown in its actual size.

In details. The code

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Image Source="{Binding Picture}" Stretch="Uniform" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

works in the same way as

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Image Source="{Binding Picture}" Stretch="None" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a value converter that will convert the checked state of the checkbox to either `Stretch.Unfiorm` or `Stretch.None`.

```
public class StretchValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return (bool)value ? Stretch.Uniform : Stretch.None;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return value.Equals(Stretch.Uniform);
  }

}
```

Then in your XAML, you can do something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>

  <local:StretchValueConverter x:Key="StretchValueConverter" />

</Window.Resources>

<CheckBox x:Name="FitToScreen" />

<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Image Source="{Binding Picture}" Stretch="{Binding ElementName=FitToScreen Converter={StaticResource StretchValueConverter}, Path=Checked"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**UPDATE**

You also need to set `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` and `VerticalScrollBarVisibilty` to `Disabled` to force the contents of the scroll viewer to not exceed the boundary. You can do this with another converter or style listening to the Checkbox.Checked property.

```
<Window x:Class="Overflow.Examples.Wpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <CheckBox x:Name="FitToScreen" Grid.Row="0" Content="Fit to screen" />

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
            <Image Source="{Binding Picture}">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Image">
                        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="None" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=FitToScreen, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>

            <ScrollViewer.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=FitToScreen, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
                            <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ScrollViewer.Style>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This will not help, I added clarification to question

Comment: SourceName="FitToScreen"  does not work here, error message appear: "error MC4110: SourceName property cannot be set within Style.Triggers section. Line 18 Position 59." (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/86f28ade-84ad-4470-bb17-f32402c34a6f/)

Comment: Wasn't aware of that limitation, and I'd have sworn I've used SourceName this way before. Alas, I haven't tested the sample, but honestly thought it would work. You may have to implement a converter afterall. When I get a chance, I'll see if I can put a working example together.

Comment: Just updated my answer to use `DataTrigger`s bound to the `CheckBox`. Still haven't had time to test this, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in xaml only using triggers applied on Image style -

```
<CheckBox x:Name="FitToScreen" />    
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Image Source="{Binding Picture}">
           <Image.Style>
              <Style TargetType="Image">
                 <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="None"/>
                 <Style.Triggers>
                     <Trigger Property="IsChecked" SourceName="FitToScreen" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"/>
                     </Trigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
           </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

**Update**

As a workaround you can place two images in a grid and play with its visibilty depending on the checkbox checked state like this -

```
<CheckBox x:Name="FitToScreen"/> 
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
     <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <Image Source="{Binding Picture}" Stretch="Uniform"
         Visibilty="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=FitToScreen, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
  <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Image Source="{Binding Picture}" Stretch="None"/>
  <ScrollViewer.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Image">
       <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" SourceName="FitToScreen" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
  </ScrollViewer.Style>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This will not help, I added clarification to question. And thanks for concise code example with xaml!

Comment: I was thought about such approach as well, but @sellmeadog provided  concise update. Anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: SourceName does not work here (ref: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/86f28ade-84ad-4470-bb17-f32402c34a6f/ )